# Change input value using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table with 10 columns and a filter modifier based on text input on each column, what I need is to create a button to change a specific filter (maybe one, maybe four, maybe all..) with custom values:

HTML code of span and tables:

```
<th class="center" rowspan="1" colspan="1">
    <span class="filter_column filter_text">
        <input type="text" class="text_filter search_init" value="Hora">
    </span>
</th>
```

Is it possible?

Well, what I want is to change the value="Hora" with a result from my own function, inside a table like all you can see on the code provided...

Comment: Can you explain a bit ?

Comment: Is what possible? What do you expect the HTML to look like after someone pushes the button?

Comment: post some code dat u tried or post a fiddle with ur code in action

Comment: I want to create a function, and make the result to replace value="wahtever" with the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the attribute of an HTML element with whatever a function returns.

Let's say you have the following BUTTON element somewhere in your HTML document:

```
<button id="myButton" name="John"> See my name. </button>
```

It is possible to change the attribute "name" using something like this in jQuery:

```
var new_name = "Colin";
$("#myButton").attr("name", new_name);
```

Therefore, if you want to change the name of this button using an arbitrary value returned by a function just make sure the function returns a string and do something like:

```
var new_name = myFunction(); // This functions returns a string.
$("#myButton").attr("name", new_name);
```

... or the more compact version:

```
$("#myButton").attr("name", myFunction());
```

But what if you want to have a function that not only changes a specific predefined value, but a value the function would pick itself? The `attr()` function in jQuery allows an object as a parameter. This object will consist in attribute/value pairs. The previous code could be instead:

```
var new_attribute = {"name": "Colin"};
$("#myButton").attr(new_attribute);
```

And just like previously done, you can have a function that returns an object `{"name": "value"}` and call that function as an argument of `.attr`.

```
var new_attr = myOtherFunction(); // This functions returns an object
$("#myButton").attr(new_attr);
```

Comment: thanks UndeadKernel, we're closer than before, but the problem is  that I need to change a the  value "hola" from "<input type="text" class="text_filter search_init" value="Hora">" when I push a button, I'm trying to build a jsfiddle to show the whole story

Comment: You should be able to change the "value" attribute of the input field with something like:
`$("input.text_filter").attr("value", "Tiempo")`

Comment: Well, I got it, the main problem is tat the code doesn't provide ID for imputs, so I can't select which I want to modify :S

Comment: Goal reached!, I've modified the code to provide an ID to each input, so now it works! THANKS!

Comment: well, now the problem is that the value inserted inside this imput must be used to filter and parsing the value this way it does nothing, but If I type it works... daaaaaaaaamn :)

Comment: You should also be able to do that as jQuery has plenty of ways to select (i.e. find) objects in the DOM. Take a look at [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) for more information about it.